# A quick way to select a line in netBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I am looking for a quick way to select a line in netBeans.

For example for copy and paste. (in vim editor `yy` yank current line)

Answer (score 7):

Most GUIs, including Netbeans, allow you to select a word by
double-clicking on it and an entire line by triple-clicking on it.

OR

selection-end-line (Shift+End)
selection-down (SHift+Down) for as many lines as you want.

Comment: `triple-clicking` is ok...except for the fact is not so practical like `command + someLetter`.

Comment: Shift+End, it will select the complete line

Comment: Not for mac users... on osx to emulate `end key` I have to make `command + arrow down`. Then If I press also `Shift` I get the line duplicated.

Comment: Shift+End only works if you're at the start of the line...  so really it would be Home then Shift + End.  @underscore666 you could type End then Shift + Home maybe?

Answer (score 7):

I've been using Netbeans for a few months.

`Ctrl + c` will copy the entire line without selecting it.

`Ctrl + e` will delete the line without selecting it.

`Ctrl + Shift + down or up` arrows will duplicate the line.

Comment: Ctrl + x copies and deletes a line

Answer (score 3):

I am late comer to this post, but with a solution. In `netbeans 8.x`, go to **Tools -> Options -> Keymap**. In that, search for `Select Line`. You will get an entry there. Under the field `Shortcut`, you can give your convenient shortcut. There is no shortcut by default